# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d245d.lib' (OpenCV 2.4.9)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, visual-c++

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.9 in Windows 7 with Visual Studio C++ 2010 Express.

I downloaded the OpenCV 2.4.9 and did the installation process according to this tutorial. Including set the environment variables.

http://opencv-srf.blogspot.com.br/2013/05/installing-configuring-opencv-with-vs.html

Except for the version of compiler, instead of "vc11" (like in the tutorial) I put "vc10".

Well, the rest I did exactly like in this tutorial.

I'm trying to run this simple code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

using namespace cv;

int main ( int argc, char **argv ) {

    Mat image = imread("9-002.tif", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    adaptiveThreshold(image, image, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 111, -20);

    imwrite("rs_9-002.tif", image);

    return 0;
}
```

And when I run the project I get this:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Projeto de TESTES, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'opencv_calib3d245d.lib'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

the properties of my project are as follows:

[image]
[image]

I do not know how to fix this. Any idea what could be causing this error?

Comment: I don't know. I downloaded from here http://opencv.org/downloads.html There is only one link for Windows, I guess it fits for both 32bits and 64bits. (I'm using Windowns 7 32bits)

Comment: Wait a minute. You have opencv-2.4.9 Your libs need to be named *249.lib not *245.lib. You need to fix all the entries in Additional Dependencies. Replace 245 with 249.

Comment: Ohhh, you're right. I had not noticed it. I put just like the tutorial but it uses a different version of OpenCV, I think that's it. I'll test here now and tell if it worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your Additional Dependencies you have listed libraries for opencv-2.4.5 not opencv-2.4.9. The libraries in your Additional Dependencies are named *245d.lib not *249d.lib. You will need to edit all the entries that have 245 in the library name and replace that with 249. Make sure you do that for all the configurations you use (Debug, Release ...).